# Obfuscating one package in a java program

Tags: java, licensing, obfuscation

Is it possible to obfuscate only one package in a Java app? I am working on converting a large free app to a licensed one. As part of that I have added a new licensing module. I want to obfuscate this code to make it harder for people to crack it. It is a relatively small module and should not be too tough to obfuscate. The entire app is however large and complex and obfuscating it will result in a lot of testing effort.

Comment: Additional testing effort? Why? Test the app before obfuscation and rely on the obfuscator. A final build acceptance test should be sufficiant.

Comment: "rely on the obfuscator" - that's something the testing folks are unwilling to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do that.  Any half decent obfuscator will allow you to choose what parts of your application are obfuscated.  Of course, details of *how* you do it will depend on the obfuscator that you are using.

---

Standard caveats about obfuscation apply: no obfuscation scheme will protect your IP against someone who has the motivation and a modicum of hacker skills.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Proguard (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) and simply set the --injars option to point to the directory(package) that you are trying to obfuscate